# Can't mount SD card as write permissions in android

Tags: android, linux

I'm using the below command to mount sd card in adb shell window, which returns an error:

```
# mount -rw -t vfat /tmp/udev/dev/mmcblk0p1 /tmp/new
mount: Device or resource busy
```

what might be the issue?

But when I'm mounting it as read only using the below command I could able to read the contents of SD card.

```
# mount -r -t vfat /tmp/udev/dev/mmcblk0p1 /tmp/new
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) ! Please read  [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) !

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure this is offtopic as this appears to be a general android question, not a programming one. This may be more appropriate on Android Enthusiasts or the Linux site.

Comment: Check if already mmcblk0p1 is mounted before your mount command execution.